# Linear ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can the following equation be solved (non trivial solutions only)?
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=y^2 $$
I am looking for non trivial solutions $y = f(x)$ and it has been a while since I have solved one of these problems. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the help! I don't know how I didn't see it lol

Comment: the ODE is not linear.  Do you know how to change the question title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation is separable, so you can write $\frac{dy}{y^2}=dx$ Therefore $\frac{-1}{y}=x+c$ and $y=\frac{-1}{x+c}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use Separation of Variables.

We end up with:

$$\int \dfrac{1}{y^2}~ dy = \int dx$$

Comment: Short and sweet, again! +1

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it just by writing
$$\frac{dy}{y^2}=dx$$ and then integrating both sides.

Comment: @PostNoBills Not for a differential equation. Non-linearity for a DE comes from multiplication of derivatives.

Comment: @PostNoBills Sorry, my mistake.